# Creating a reusable DictWriter context manager

Tags: python, file

I want to simplify the repetitive work of creating a `DictWriter` in a `with` context manager.

So I created a `@contextmanager` decorated `DictWriter`, and yielded that, to use in my code. Is this correct?

This seems to work, but yielding from within a `with` seems redundant.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import pathlib
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def dict_writer(path, headers):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers, extrasaction='ignore')
        writer.writeheader()
        yield writer


def main():
    path = pathlib.Path('~/Desktop/test.csv').expanduser()
    headers = ['site', 'user']
    with dict_writer(path, headers) as writer:
        writer.writerow({'site': 1, 'user': 'foo'})  # Works
    writer.writerow({})  # Causes: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please post your test cases so that we might help you to augment them.

Comment: @pacmaninbw the `main()` function is the test case. As I said, it currently appears to work as expected.